# how to identify that XML parsing has been finished?

Tags: iphone

how can i identify that  XML parsing has been finished? any method is there to be called
at the end of parsing all data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use NSXMLParser:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
```

> Sent by the parser object to the
>   delegate when it has successfully
>   completed parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and when you reach the enclosing end element process it accordingly

```
(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Answer (score 0):

Most standard XML parsers either create a complete DOM or explicitly expose the SAX API (http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html). The SAX API has a specific `endDocument()` method after which you can assume that the document has been completely read. The DOM methods do not have a universal API but a typical example is given by XOM (http://www.xom.nu) with a call:

```
Document doc = new Builder().build(myInstream);
```

This either completes satisfactorily or throws an exception.

There are other tools such as StAX (http://stax.codehaus.org/Home) which allow partial parsing.